# Making my executable of a program available for partners to use on their website?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud

I have a proprietary scientific algorithm in C and it has been compiled.

I want a 3rd party website(s) to able to run it from their web sites - can I put the executable on Google/One/Drive, Dropbox or another drive ... or what environment does it have to be in so that it can be run?

- I really do not want anyone to download the executable
- It supposed to be for a specific partner to utilize
- For my program, the input has to come from my partner's site. What do I do to get the input from his website?

Comment: Do you want other people to be able to download it and run it by them selfs? Or you want other website to just invoke your code that lives somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: I just want the website to invoke the code. Where could I put it in the cloud initially for free .. maybe later I will be able to pay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server which you have permissions to run executables. 
The beginning of the solution will be to install a server with a we server application like Apache. 
Then to enable some server side scripting language like php or cgi. 
Write an html/php page that calls that  c program you wrote and return a response in some parsable form like JSON or XML.

The web page will be invoked with data from the other website, like query parameters, post payload etc.

This is not a simple or quick solution.

If this code can be migrated to javascript , then it will be much easier, but you will have to share your source code.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me: My partner has a website application. My code has to be run from his site. For my executable, the input has to come from my partner's site.

Comment: Please see the answer again, I have edited it regarding your comment.  I don't think any free cloud service will allow running c code. It is too dangerous. You either have to set up your own server or migrate your code to another language which is more web friendly, like php or javascript.

Comment: Are u saying that it is recommended that the C code is also re-written in another language - if so what might be a more Unix friendly language? I am a bit confused because you said I have a web page that calls the C code. This webpage is also invoked by another web site - is this correct? Appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Free or cheap web hosting services will not allow you to run c code on their servers. So if you have to stay in c, you will have to set up your own server, and run the code with cgi or php.   A different solution is to write the code in php or javascript, and that way it will be easier to host it on a free or cheap cloud service.

Comment: Please google cgi, JavaScript and php. It might get you closer to a solution.